# How to manage a database connection in an R Package

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I'm building an R package, the main purpose of which is to abstract away the pain of dealing with a proprietary database that requires some fairly complex SQL queries in order get data out.

As such, the connection to the Microsoft SQL Server (obtained by `odbcDriverConnect`) is a constant and important part of this package, but I can't work out how best to manage this and I'm hoping for advice as to how this should be implemented in R.

My current thoughts are:

1. Make the user ensure they have a valid connection before they call any function. Each function then has `connection` as a parameter which must be passed. This puts a burden on the user.
2. In every function, make a call to `get.connection()` which will get new connection each time. Old connections are then allowed to timeout naturally, which seems a sloppy approach.
3. As above, but return the same connection each time. This appears not to be a viable proposition as I can't prevent connections from timing out through R. `autoReconnect=TRUE` and other tricks I've used in different languages seem to have no effect.

In Java, I would probably have a DatabaseConnectionPool populated with a number of connections and simply grab connections from, and return them to, that pool as needed. I also don't seem to have the timeout issue in Java when I specify `autoReconnect=TRUE`.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`pool` is an R package for pooling connections such as databases.  If you're cool to use a github package, take a look at https://github.com/rstudio/pool.  Will reuse or recreate the connection as required.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a mix between the second and the third approach is a reasonable solution i.e. getting the same connection each time, however before returning the connection you can [check if it is still opened](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RODBC-package-how-to-check-whether-connection-is-open-td888610.html), otherwise create a new connection.

It is basically as if you are manually implementing `autoReconnect=TRUE`